Neither `xarray.ufuncs.exp()` nor `xr.apply_ufunc.exp()` work: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'exp'`
I am trying to make some old code run, but running in circles with exponentiation an array. Neither xarray.ufuncs.exp() nor xr.apply_ufunc.exp() work.
Some suggested there is a bug in dask, which should be solved by pip install dask==2.4.0, but that did not help either.
Please help!
